# How can i convert String into JSON array?

Tags: php, arrays, string, codeigniter

I am integrating Third Party API and in Response, they are sending in the below format but I want to convert in JSON array

Response:

```
$str = '[[name,class,rollno],[abhishek,tenth,556],[Rahul,Nine,20]]';
**Response is in String format
```

Want to convert:

```
 [{"name":"abhishek","class":"tenth","rollno":"50"},{"name":"Rahul","class":"nine","rollno":"20"}]
```

Comment: Cool. Good luck. Let us know if you run into any issues at some point when you're trying to do it. If you do, then show us what you've tried and where the issue is, since SO isn't a free coding service. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson i didn't get any idea how i do that, main issue is that i am getting response in string. Can you help me ?

Comment: If that is the actual string you're getting, then you have more issues, since that's not a valid JSON string.

Comment: yes I am getting the response in actual String, not a JSON string.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this

```
$str = '[[name,class,rollno],[abhishek,tenth,556],[Rahul,Nine,20]]';

// match all inside [] e.g. name,class,rollno
preg_match_all('/\[?\[(.*?)\]/m', $str, $matches);

// set 1st match value as keys
$keys = explode(',', array_shift($matches[1]));

// map then combine keys with each data group
$result = array_map(function($e) use ($keys) {
    return array_combine($keys, explode(',', $e));
}, $matches[1]);

echo json_encode($result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like following.

```
<?php
$str = '[[name,class,rollno],[abhishek,tenth,556],[Rahul,Nine,20]]';
$str1 = ltrim($str,'[');
$str2 = rtrim($str1,']');
$ar = explode("],[",$str2);

$arkey = explode(',',$ar[0]);
for($i = 1; $i < count($ar); $i++){ 
    $val = explode(',', $ar[$i]);   
    $new[] = array($arkey[0] => $val[0],$arkey[1] => $val[1],$arkey[2] => $val[2]);
}
```

Now :

```
print_r(json_encode($new));
```

Result will be :

```
[{"name":"abhishek","class":"tenth","rollno":"556"},{"name":"Rahul","class":"Nine","rollno":"20"}]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Kawaljeet Singh.